# Why am I getting "Error: Connection error. Please try again."?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a query which typically does not require "`AllowLargeResults`" to be set but I am returned the error

```
"Error: Response too large to return.Job ID: job_i0ZwEeECZWZk7YfpP9BNBYja8oc".
```

In response I then enable "**AllowLargeResults**" and I get

```
"Error: Connection error. Please try again. Job ID: job_w1aTc8OR94sEw9OJHm_K4vc9C-A".
```

The query which produces these errors runs every night and has been working without fail for sometime now. I expect some sort of change the developers made to the product have caused this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an engineer on BigQuery. There are two problems:

1. There is an internal error when using some letter combinations as a table alias name in a join. As a workaround, try using "x" instead of "d" for the alias of the inner-most join. We are investigating.
2. We have a code path that mistakenly surfaces generic errors, so you are seeing "Connection error" instead of a more descriptive error. We're working to fix that.